# Check ip is present within file & update iptables bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, iptables

I want to check that the ip is present within the ccd folder and push the ip route to the FORWARDING chain in the iptables. Im new to bash scripting and need a little help finishing this script.

client file in /etc/openvpn/ccd :

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.45 255.255.255.0
push 'route 10.10.0.45'
```

I need to grep `10.8.0.45 & 10.10.0.45`

and push those routes in the iptables.
e.g

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.45 -d 10.10.0.45 -j ACCEPT
```

client-connect /etc/openvpn/on_connect.sh

script I need help with 'grep' or 'awk'

```
static_ip=  cat $CCD_DIR/$common_name | grep -w "ifconfig-push" | awk -F ' ' {'print $2'}

ip_destination=cat $CCD_DIR/$common_name | grep -w "push 'route" | awk -F ' ' {'print $3'}  | tr -d "'"
```

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
> #
> #  Add iptables rules based on CCD client config.
> #
>
> CCD_DIR="/etc/openvpn/ccd"
>
> RULE_COMMENT="FORWARD"$common_name
> static_ip=cat $CCD_DIR/$common_name | grep -w "ifconfig-push" | awk -F ' ' {'print $2'}.
> ip_destination=cat $CCD_DIR/$common_name | grep -w "push 'route" | awk -F ' ' {'print $3'}  | tr -d "'"
>
>
>
> if [ -f $CCD_DIR/$common_name ]; then
>   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s $static_ip -d ip_destination -j ACCEPT
> fi
>
> exit 0
> ```

Edit: I think my usage of cat is wrong .

Comment: Use command substitution to assign result of a command to a variable. `var=$(command | grep | awk | something | while read line; do echo "$line"; done)`. `cat | grep` is usuless use of `cat`, just do `grep -w "ifconfig-push" "$CCD_DIR/$common_name"`. Remember to quote your variable expansions to protect against filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
static_ip=$( cat $CCD_DIR | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep -E '(^|\s)10.8.0.45($|\s)' )
ip_destination=$( cat $CCD_DIR | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" | grep -E '(^|\s)10.10.0.45($|\s)' )
```

So first you grep all IP's address in file and then you search exactly what you need

Edited after your comment.

If I understand correctly,
"ifconfig-push" - Is only one peer ccd file ?
so you can use this :

```
static_ip=$( grep -w "ifconfig-push" | awk -F ' ' {'print $2'})
```

For the rest in "push route" you need to use loop to find all matching ip address and put them to the iptables.

```
if [ -f $CCD_DIR/$common_name ]
then
 cat $CCD_DIR | awk -F 'route' {'print $2'} | awk -F ' ' {'print $1'} | sed '/^$/d' | grep -E "\b(10)\.(8)\.(0)\.|(10)\.(10)\.(0).\b" | while read ip_destination
 do
  sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s $static_ip -d ip_destination -j ACCEPT
 done
fi
```